# When using less-watch-compiler I sporadically get error message "Does not exist" and then it stops working

Tags: node.js, less

I am using the less-watch-compiler installed by npm.  I am using it to precompile .less files into .css files.  The command line I am running is :

$ npx less-watch-compiler src/ public/dist/

I get this "Does not exist" error for no apparent reason:

[image]

Not sure why it should work while I am editing the file in the first couple of edits and then suddenly stop working.  Does anyone know why?

I was expecting for it to not stop working after a couple of edits to main.less